# angular2 template binding unicode

Tags: angular, unicode

im trying to show some symbols in angular2 template.
This works fine:

```
<div>&#xe911;</div>
```

This works, too:

```
<div>{{"&#xe911"}}</div> //colon elided
```

But this doesn't:

```
<div>{{getSymbol()}}</div>
```

whith

```
private symbol(): string {
    //return this.access.accessLevel >= AccessLevel.expert ? "\e911" : "\e917";
    return this.access.accessLevel >= AccessLevel.expert ? "&#xe911;" : "&#xe917;";
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With string interpolation, `{{}}` is treated as a text string. You should use `innerHtml` binding to get actual html in your element:

```
<div [innerHtml]="getSymbol()"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple solution.

Comment: Works for me. Straight forward solution

Comment: To prevent angular changedetection to call getSymbol instantly - I just assigned text to prop and specify prop instead of a function call.